# java script not calling in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having some trouble .

I have the following view in my mvc application:

```
@model Radio_Management_Interface.Models.Blocks.blocks_create

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Create Block";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_main.cshtml";
}

<script>
 function getSelectedValue(sel) {
    window.alert("You change the combo box");
}
</script>


<div class="contenttitle">
  <h2 class="form"><span>Create A New Block</span></h2>
</div><!--contenttitle-->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Blocks", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "stdform" }))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <hr />
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<p>
    <label>Select Network</label>
    <span class="field">
        <select name="select" onclick="getSelectedValue">
            @foreach (var item in Model.networks)
            {
                <option value="@item.networkID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.block.start)
    <small class="desc">Name of the customer.</small>
</p>
```

The specific part of concern is:

```
<select name="select" onclick="getSelectedValue">
```

Why would this event not be being called? When I change the option in the select element on the site my JavaScript file doesn't run.  Why could this be?

Answer (score 2):

You want to be using the `onchange` event rather than `onclick` and pass it something as your method expects a parameter:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="select" onchange="getSelectedValue(this)">
```

**JS:**

```
function getSelectedValue(sel) {
    window.alert(document.getElementById(sel.value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the brackets, and also it should be the change event -  onchange="getSelectedValue()"

Answer (score 0):

A select uses the change event rather than onclick.

You can use jQuery to wire-up the event like this:

```
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).val() + " ";
    });
    window.alert( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

jQuery is unobtrusive so does not mix functionality up with html and gracefully handles errors rather than using the obtrusive method that is embedded into the html.